# Esquema de fila para código em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, api, fila

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com uma dúvida / necessidade que não achei como fazer. Tenho um código que uso para rodar vários CNPJs através da API da Sintegra, onde com o resultado retornado por esta eu alimento as informações em um Banco de Dados. O problema está sendo o seguinte, quando é retornado um status diferente de OK desta API na busca, o Sistema acaba parando e não continua a rodar a quantidade que determinei na Query. Há algum forma de fazer uma especie de fila, onde quando o código for diferente de OK, ele apenas pule para o próximo e não tentei ficar rodando o que está dando erro ?

consulta.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
set_time_limit(0);
include "conexao.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$query = "SELECT id_fornecedor, cnpj FROM fornecedores WHERE status_consulta = 'N'";
$fornecedores = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($connect, $query), MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Informações para a chamada da API
$token = "";
$plugin = "ST";

foreach ($fornecedores as $key => $fornecedor) {
    //URL do serviço
    $service_url = "https://sintegraws.com.br/api/v1/execute-api.php?token=" . $token . "&cnpj=" . $fornecedor['cnpj'] . "&plugin=" . $plugin;

    //Faz a chamada da API

    $response = file_get_contents($service_url);


    //Aqui fazemos o parse do json retornado
    $json = json_decode($response);

    $nome_fornecedor = utf8_decode($json->nome_empresarial);
    $situacao_cnpj = utf8_decode($json->situacao_cnpj);
    $situacao_ie = utf8_decode($json->situacao_ie);
    $mensagem = utf8_decode($json->message);


    //Aqui exibimos uma mensagem caso tenha ocorrido algum erro
    if ($json->status != 'OK') {
        if ($json->message === "CNPJ inválido.") {
            $query = "UPDATE fornecedores SET nome_fornecedor = NULL, situacao_cnpj = NULL, situacao_ie = NULL, status_consulta = 'P', mensagem = '$mensagem',
        dtAtt = NOW() WHERE id_fornecedor = " . $fornecedor['id_fornecedor'];
        } else {
            die("Erro " . $json->code . ": " . $json->message);
        }

    }

    $query = "UPDATE fornecedores SET nome_fornecedor = '$nome_fornecedor', situacao_cnpj = '$situacao_cnpj', situacao_ie = '$situacao_ie', status_consulta = 'P', mensagem = '$mensagem',
    dtAtt = NOW() WHERE id_fornecedor = " . $fornecedor['id_fornecedor'];


    if (mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
        $_SESSION['fornecedores_atualizados'] = true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['fornecedores_erro'] = true;
    }
}
```

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Atualiza Fornecedores - SINTEGRA</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <style>
      #enviar {
        padding: 13px 15px;
        border: 1px solid green;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #138c13;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="consulta.php" method="POST">
     <button type="submit" id="enviar">Atualizar Fornecedores</button> <br>

     <p>Atualizados: </p>

     <p>Desatualizados: </p>

    </form>

    <?php
      if (isset($_SESSION['fornecedores_atualizados'])):
    ?>

    <div>
      <p>Fornecedores atualizados com sucesso !</p>
    </div>

    <?php
    endif;
    unset($_SESSION['fornecedores_atualizados']);
    ?>

    <?php
      if (isset($_SESSION['fornecedores_erro'])):
    ?>

    <div>
      <p> Houve um erro ao atualizar os fornecedores. <?= mysqli_error($connect) ?></p>
    </div>

    <?php
    endif;
    unset($_SESSION['fornecedores_erro']);
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

O sistema roda assim que clico neste botão que fica no Index, e eu sempre coloco um intervalo de CNPJs na Query, está sem no código pois eu ja hávia rodado todos e apenas queria conferir os que haviam retornado erros.

Comment: faz um if caso caia dentro do erro ele você incrementa ele para pular para o próximo... Talvez resolva, mas não é o recomendado.

Comment: Pode fazer mais simples, dentro do bloco ` if ($json->status != 'OK') {`, antes do `}else` adicione um `continue;`, ele simplesmente vai passar pelo continue e vai continuar o processo

Answer (score 0):

Olá, basta adicionar um continue no else e ele vai pular para o próximo item.

Conforme abaixo:

```html
<?php
session_start();
set_time_limit(0);
include "conexao.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$query = "SELECT id_fornecedor, cnpj FROM fornecedores WHERE status_consulta = 'N'";
$fornecedores = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($connect, $query), MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Informações para a chamada da API
$token = "";
$plugin = "ST";

foreach ($fornecedores as $key => $fornecedor) {
    //URL do serviço
    $service_url = "https://sintegraws.com.br/api/v1/execute-api.php?token=" . $token . "&cnpj=" . $fornecedor['cnpj'] . "&plugin=" . $plugin;

    //Faz a chamada da API

    $response = file_get_contents($service_url);


    //Aqui fazemos o parse do json retornado
    $json = json_decode($response);

    $nome_fornecedor = utf8_decode($json->nome_empresarial);
    $situacao_cnpj = utf8_decode($json->situacao_cnpj);
    $situacao_ie = utf8_decode($json->situacao_ie);
    $mensagem = utf8_decode($json->message);


    //Aqui exibimos uma mensagem caso tenha ocorrido algum erro
    if ($json->status != 'OK') {
        if ($json->message === "CNPJ inválido.") {
            $query = "UPDATE fornecedores SET nome_fornecedor = NULL, situacao_cnpj = NULL, situacao_ie = NULL, status_consulta = 'P', mensagem = '$mensagem',
        dtAtt = NOW() WHERE id_fornecedor = " . $fornecedor['id_fornecedor'];
        } else {
            die("Erro " . $json->code . ": " . $json->message);
        }

    } else {
        // vai pular para o próximo da fila
        continue;
    }

    $query = "UPDATE fornecedores SET nome_fornecedor = '$nome_fornecedor', situacao_cnpj = '$situacao_cnpj', situacao_ie = '$situacao_ie', status_consulta = 'P', mensagem = '$mensagem',
    dtAtt = NOW() WHERE id_fornecedor = " . $fornecedor['id_fornecedor'];


    if (mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
        $_SESSION['fornecedores_atualizados'] = true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['fornecedores_erro'] = true;
    }
}
```